# JavaScript : How do i convert "4/10/2016, 4:00:00PM" to 4 PM?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, datetime-format, datetimeoffset

How do i convert "4/10/2016, 4:00:00PM" to 4 PM in javascript? Do i need to use substring or do we have any date method to do this conversion? Kindly advice.

JSFiddle : https://goo.gl/rppCaq

Comment: `s[0]+s.slice(-2)` ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the code?

Comment: String methods are preferred since you have to parse the string to get a Date anyway, then call methods to format the output. You might as well just parse the string to the format you want and skip the Date.

Comment: Why are you linking to jsfiddle using goo.gl ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/(\d+)(?=:\d+:\d+)|([A-Z]+)(?=$)/g` to match digit followed by `":"` followed by digit followed by `":"` followed by digit, or `"A"` through `"Z"` followed by end of input; `Array.prototype.join()` with space character `" "` as parameter

```js
var date = "4/10/2016, 4:00:00PM";
var res = date.match(/(\d+)(?=:\d+:\d+)|([A-Z]+)(?=$)/g);
document.body.textContent = res.join(" ");
```

Comment: sorry, this is not working on Internet Explorer 11 :(

Comment: @user5970552 _"this is not working on Internet Explorer 11"_ Can you describe "not working" ?

Comment: Same piece of code which you gave is working fine on Firefox and not on IE11

Comment: will debug and let you know after sometime

Comment: date.match sentence is just giving PM instead of 4 PM. But the same code is working fine on Windows 10, IE11, but it is not working on Windows 7, IE11 :(

Comment: @user5970552 Interesting. Not certain how that could occur ? Try `var date = "4/10/2016, 4:00:00PM"; date.match(/\s\d+(?=:)|[a-z]+$/ig).join(" ").trim()`

Comment: @user5970552 Have you tried to ask another user having same versions of os and browser to try ? To see if the results you received are reproduced ?

Comment: I found the problem. My actual data doesn't have comma (,) between date and time. So regex fails in IE and Firefox okay with that

Comment: Can you please update regex without comma in the date value like"4/10/2016 4:00:00PM"

Comment: Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: @user5970552 The comma should not matter. The `RegExp` does not check for comma. You could break the process into parts to determine which returns expected results `var date = "4/10/2016 4:00:00PM"; /* no comma included */ var num = date.match(/\d+(?=:)/), word = date.match(/[A-Z]+$/), res = "" + num +" "+ word;` should return same result as `"4/10/2016 4:00:00PM".match(/(\d+)(?=:\d+:\d+)|([A-Z]+)(?=$)/g).join(" ")`

Comment: Hmm . you are right. I think the issue occurs when a single digit month comes as the month. The regex works fine with the double digit months and it has problem with the single digit months.

Comment: "4/7/2016, 4:00:00 PM"

Comment: @user5970552 _"I think the issue occurs when a single digit month comes as the month. The regex works fine with the double digit months and it has problem with the single digit months."_ The month should not be captured at all. `/\d+(?=:)/` matches digits followed by colon `:` character, not `/` forward slash character. `"4/7/2016, 4:00:00 PM"` returns same results , here. If you are referring to double digit hour, `"4/7/2016, 12:00:00 PM".match(/(\d+)(?=:\d+:\d+)|([A-Z]+)(?=$)/g).join(" ")` returns `"12 PM"` here

Comment: still i am not getting the result, created a jsfiddle, could you please check https://jsfiddle.net/etpo99ua/20/

Comment: @user5970552 `d2`, `d3` , `d4`, `d5`  are invalid dates. When `d6 =d5.match(/(\d+)(?=:\d+:\d+)|([A-Z]+)(?=$)/g).join(" ");` line is reached `console` displays `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of null` , as `d5` is `undefined` . Did you check `console` at https://jsfiddle.net/etpo99ua/20/ ? Original Question does not include use of `new Date()` ? What are you trying to achieve using `new Date()` ?

Comment: Sorry. I got confused for myself :(.. I have updated the fiddle as per your code. can you please check https://jsfiddle.net/etpo99ua/23/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105399/discussion-between-user5970552-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a custom String as date, try something like below. It is not very pretty but will get the work done for this scenario.

```
var timeArr = "4/10/2016, 4:00:00PM".split(', ')[1].split(':');

var hr = timeArr[0];
var min = timeArr[1];
var sec = timeArr[2].match(/\d/g).join('');
var ampm = timeArr[2].replace(sec, '');

console.log(hr, min, sec, ampm );
```

Answer (score 1):

As with other answers, just mess with the string:

```js
function getHours(s) {
  var b = (s.split(' ')[1] || '').match(/\d+|[a-z]+/ig) || [];
  return /^\d+$/.test(b[0]) && /^[a-z]/i.test(b[3])? b[0] + ' ' + b[3] : 'can\'t parse that...';
}

document.write(getHours('4/10/2016, 4:00:00PM'));
document.write('<br>' + getHours('parse this'));
```

Comment: still i am not getting the result, created a jsfiddle, could you please https://jsfiddle.net/etpo99ua/20/